# Rescale JFrame content

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I am creating a `JFrame`, and when the window is expanded I want the content to stay centered, instead of staying the same distance away from the side. I am using WindowBuilder on Eclipse.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for some more ideas

Answer (score 3):

One way, have the container use a GridBagLayout and add the single content to the container without constraints.

For example:

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CenteredContent extends JPanel {
   public static final String IMG_PATH = "https://duke.kenai.com/iconSized/duke.gif";

   public CenteredContent() throws IOException {
      URL imgUrl = new URL(IMG_PATH);
      BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
      Icon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
      JLabel label = new JLabel(imgIcon);

      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      add(label);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      CenteredContent mainPanel = null;
      try {
         mainPanel = new CenteredContent();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      }

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("CenteredContent");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't find that layout. How can I remove constraints?

Comment: @CaffeineToCode: I'm not sure that I understand your question. Are you saying that you can't **find** the layout? What do you mean by "find" as it's part of core Java? And you don't have to remove the constraints, you simply don't add them. Please Google `java gridbaglayout tutorial` -- first hit.

Comment: To clarify, I'm using the Eclipse WindowBuilder. There is no GridBagLayout, but there is a GridLayout. Is that it?

Comment: *"I'm using the Eclipse WindowBuilder."*  No.. it seems it's using you.  Learn how to write Java, and you might master it.

Comment: @CaffeineToCode: No, GridLayout is not the same as GridBagLayout. You're better off coding something like this by hand and not using code generation. In fact I strongly advise you not to use a windows builder when you're new to the GUI library. Learn the library first, and then consider using the code generation tool, else you'll paint yourself in a corner.